# Discord py: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'CommandOnCooldown'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need help, i have been trying to solve this for so long.
It worked before but now it does not anymore.

I want the bot to send a message if the command is still on cooldown, but it does not work anymore, all it just tells me this in the console:

**Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'CommandOnCooldown'
**

Note: this is only some part of the code, i think i do not have to include my bot token in here.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="++", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="Dev: "))



@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)
async def daily(ctx):
    # Read balance from balances.txt
    try:
        with open(f'{ctx.author.id}.txt', 'r+') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
            balance = 0
            # Get the current user's balance
            for line in lines:
                user_id_and_balance = line.split(':')
                if user_id_and_balance[0] == user_id:
                    balance = int(user_id_and_balance[1])
                    break

            # Calculate bonus
            bonus = random.randint(1, 1000) * 15

            # Update balance and send message
            new_balance = balance + bonus
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name} claimed their daily bonus!", description=f"You earned `{bonus}`:dollar: as your daily bonus.\nYour new balance is `{new_balance}` :dollar:.\n\n*This command has a cooldown of 24 hours.*", color=0x000000)
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}", embed=embed)

            # Replace the current user's balance
            for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                user_id_and_balance = line.split(':')
                if user_id_and_balance[0] == user_id:
                    lines[i] = f"{user_id}:{new_balance}\n"
                    break

            # Write new balance to balances.txt
            with open(f'{ctx.author.id}.txt', 'w+') as f:
                f.writelines(lines)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}", description=f"You do not have a balance. Please use the `++reset` command to create one.\n\n*This command has a cooldown of 24 hours.*", color=0x000000)
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}", embed=embed)



@daily.error
async def daily_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        remaining_time = error.retry_after
        await ctx.send(f"You need to wait {remaining_time:.0f} seconds before claiming your daily bonus again.")
```

I tried many different things but nothing really helped, i am hoping for help.

Comment: Do you have a function named `commands`?

Comment: You my guy, are a genius, i had a function named commands to list all commands, ofc it has no attribute CommandOnCooldown, i changed that name of the function and it worked.